# Is there a way to pause a running script with process.stdin for user input in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prompt, readline

I was hoping to see if Node.js has the ability to pause a script once it hits a process.stdin block to take in user input for command-line applications, similar to how *prompt()* works with JS in the browser or how *gets* works in Ruby.

```
  var response = '';

  console.log("What's your favorite color?");

  process.stdin.resume();
  process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

  process.stdin.on('data', function (text) {
    response = text;
    process.exit();
  });

  console.log(`Cool! So ${response} is your favorite color? Mine is black.`);
```

In the simple script above, I would hope to see

```
What's your favorite color?
*pause for user input ===>* Red
Cool! So Red is your favorite color? Mine is black.
```

with the pause halting the script until I type something and hit enter for it to continue running. Instead, I see

```
What's your favorite color?
Cool! So  is your favorite color? Mine is black.
```

immediately printed out and THEN accepts user input from me.

I am aware there are other modules like *readline* and *prompt* that simplify taking in user input for node. For this question, I'm particularly looking to see if Node.js offers this functionality without having to install extra packages(process.stdin is the first thing that comes to mind), although it would be helpful to know if any modules provide that kind of functionality as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use readline-sync.

```
var rl = require('readline-sync');
var response = '';

response = rl.question("What's your favorite color?");

console.log(`Cool! So ${response} is your favorite color? Mine is black.`);
```

Comment: This definitely fits the bill functionality-wise. But do you know if there's a way to achieve this without installing a package like readline-sync? Just with node?

Comment: Installing packages is a common task in Node. Don't worry about it, @CaryMeskell.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait for the stdin before continuing your script

```
  var response = '';

  console.log("What's your favorite color?");

  process.stdin.resume();
  process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

  process.stdin.on('data', function (text) {
    response = text;
    console.log(`Cool! So ${response} is your favorite color? Mine is black.`);
    process.exit();
  });
```

Comment: Hmm, this works well for the small example. But if the script was much larger with many questions and answers, I'm not sure if it would flow correctly

Comment: @CaryMeskell, this is a common problem with Node apps - it has no synchronous I/O. So you have to find a good way to deal with this (promises, more event handlers, some package like `async`, etc).

Comment: Everyone suggests to use promises but no one has provided an example

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for :

first add this in your file :

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const util = require('util');
const question = util.promisify(rl.question).bind(rl);
```

both `readline` and `util` are native modules from Node.js

Then you can set functions to ask question like this :

```
async function questionExample() {
  try {
    const answer = await question('What is you favorite food? ');
    return answer;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Question rejected', err);
  }
  
}
```

Then you can simply ask your questions like this :

```
    async function main() {
    
        let answer = await questionExample(); // wait till an answer is received for the question
        console.log(`your answer is ${answer}`);
        
        // or ask question directly like this
        answer = await question('Is this a new question ?');
        console.log(`your answer is ${answer}`);

        rl.close();
    
    };
    
    main();
```

It comes from the utilisation of the [rl.question(query[, options], callback)](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/readline.html#readline_rl_question_query_options_callback) method as it's util.promisify()ed version from the Node.js documentation.

It's better to use `readline` this way than the `readline-sync` module as `readline-sync` present an encoding issue on the input if you aren't using special chars you could go along with readline-sync as it will not represent an issue for you.